# windows mobile 6.5 UI

Tags: c#, windows-mobile-6.5

i'm a beginner in developing app in windows mobile 6.5 ? and our project actually depending on how nice is our UI !!

and when i open a new smart device project in C# to implement our UI design, i found that the toolbox of the compact framework (textboxs ,buttons ..etc) is not good enough to make a nice UI ...so is there any suggestion to implement this UI by another way to be nice ?!?!

thank u in advance

Answer (score 0):

My company uses the [Resco Mobile toolkit](http://www.resco.net/developer/mobileformstoolkit/overview.aspx).  It's not free, but the UI elements are a lot nice and have a lot more functionality than the built-in Windows Mobile Forms.

Comment: i need just a tutorial to learn how to use Resco mobileforms toolkot

Answer (score 0):

You have all the freedom to define the visual appeareance of the controls. Have a look at [Silvermoon](http://silvermoon.codeplex.com/), for example...

Comment: can u give me a link or the give me the steps for how to use this with win 6.5 ? thnx

Comment: Well, there is everything included in the package: Documentation, examples, tutorials. The basic principle is simple: The framework defines a new set of controls which are rendered using OpenGL API. The results are impressive at devices which have a hardware support for OpenGL rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You should buy/find-free controls library.

Maybe the better way would be to make your own controls using GDI+ to have more control.